# Update (from p:ajax) Primefaces datatable select all rows of the table

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, datatable, primefaces

I have the same issue with primefaces 2.2.1
I use Spinner component with Ajax. For each change on the spinner I want to update a (primefaces) DataTable component. And I don't know why, each time I update datatable, all rows are selected even though selectionMode="single" and selection takes  a parameter which is a POJO and not a list. This happens in a composite implementation.

```
<h:form id="frm">
        (...)
                    <p:dataTable id="openingHoursTbl" var="oh" value="#{cc.attrs.openingHours}" rows="7"
                       selection="#{cc.attrs.selectedHours}" selectionMode="single"
                       onRowSelectUpdate="hoursTable"
                       style="width: 300px">

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Day" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{oh.displayedDays}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Opening Hours" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText id="ohHeader" value="#{oh.displayedHours}" />
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                (...)
                            <p:spinner value="#{hour.fromHour}" maxlength="2" size="2" stepFactor="1" min="0" max="23">  
                                <p:ajax process="@form" update="#{cc.clientId}:frm:openingHoursTbl" event="change" />
                            </p:spinner>
                (...)
    </h:form>
```

Here is the response received from the server (notice that selection input tag have all rows selected):

```
<partial-response>
<changes>
    <update id="j_idt162:frm:openingHoursTbl">
        <div id="j_idt162:frm:openingHoursTbl" class="ui-datatable ui-widget"
            style="width: 300px">
            <table>
                (...)
            </table>
            <input type="hidden" id="j_idt162:frm:openingHoursTbl_selection"
                name="j_idt162:frm:openingHoursTbl_selection" value="0,1,2,3,4,5,6" />
        (...)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is a little much to sort through... please try to set up a SSCCE, http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I recently had a similar problem so it might help someone else who has the same problem.
The issue I had was when deleting a row, so not quite the same but anyhow.

I had to reset the "selected value" when I deleted a row. So I guess this could be avoided by updating the data set you're working with.